# How do I traverse a 2D array like an onion layer by layer and rearrange layers into a new 2D array in the most efficient way?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I was trying to implement this idea (from the title) and the code ended up being very inefficient, is there an efficient way to do this (without using a library)?

Example Input:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8],
[9, 10, 11, 12],
[13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

into

```
[[5,9,13,1,2,3,4],[10,14,6,7,8],[15,11,12],[16]]
```

(Ideal test case with all 0s and 1s:

input:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

into

```
[[1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0]]
```

I attempted using numpy but I also want to achieve this without using a library (otherwise it wouldn't be a problem):

```
import numpy as np


rows = [
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]

columns = np.array([list(column[i+1:]) for i, column in enumerate(zip(*rows))])
rows = np.array([row[i:] for i, row in enumerate(rows)])


print(columns + rows)
```